# unable to create schema in MarkLogic database

Tags: schema, marklogic, nosql

I used the following syntax from documentation

```
curl -X POST  --anyauth --user admin:admin \
  --header "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -d '{"view-schema-name": "mySchema"}' \
  http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/SQLdata/view-schemas?format=json
```

your thoughts please! TIA

**Error msg -**

> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 9
>   {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"415", "status":"Unsupported Media Type", "messag
>   eCode":"REST-INVALIDMIMETYPE", "message":"REST-INVALIDMIMETYPE: (rest:INVALIDMIM
>   ETYPE) Content-Type must be one of:  'application/json', 'application/xml', Rece
>   ived: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}}

Comment: The response of the curl command you ran may be helpful..

Comment: I just ran your curl command without error, after changing to use the Documents database. What version of MarkLogic are you using? What OS?

Comment: using 8.0-3.2 enterprise edition. windows 8. can u pls share the code to understand the syntax? thx

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned before, the output of your cUrl command will be helpful. But without that, the only error I can imagine from your sample is of the database SQLdata does not exist..

Comment: There is not message - perhaps update your original question and add it in there.

Comment: I have posted the error msg and there is SQLdata db in MarkLogic server